# Issue migrating galleries has created shortcode with urls rather than IDs - any fix for this?

Tags: gallery, migration, import, bulk-import

I've had to rebuild a site from scratch on a new platform, everything has worked fine using a mix of the built in import/export tools and WP All Import/Export.

The only issue I'm facing is with the gallery short codes, I'm getting the urls pulled through rather than IDs. I presume this is due to the images now having new IDs when imported to the site.

The WP Import All has created the below rather than id=1,2,3 etc...

`[gallery ids="http://domain.com/.../image01.jpg|Image description 01,"http://domain.com/.../image02.jpg|Image description 02"http://domain.com/.../image03.jpg|Image description 03" link="file"]`

Is there a way around this or import method that works for galleries?

Comment: Are galleries only imported like this using WP All Import, or does the WordPress Importer plugin also import them like this? Are you able to check whether this change has been made during the import or whether this is how they're represented in the export?

Comment: If imported using the Wordpress importer then the format is correct using IDs rather than the image urls however these IDs don't relate to the correct images. Presume the ID have been created on importing the new images to the media library folders.